# Image not saving in database(mysql) and displaying null as blob in django

Tags: mysql, django

I am saving 4 images from the user (maybe it will be null). I do not want to save the images in a directory or folder,I need to save the images in db(mysql). The 'form.save' is working and after looking in db the **blob is present but there is **no data** in it**.Not only that the ****null** is displaying as blob**!

forms.py

```
  class ClientCreateForm(ModelForm):
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    signature = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    poi_image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    poa_image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

model.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
       
    photo = models.ImageField(db_column='PHOTO', blank=True, null=True)  
    signature = models.ImageField(db_column='SIGNATURE', blank=True, null=True)  
    poi_image = models.ImageField(db_column='POI_IMAGE', blank=True, null=True)  
    poa_image = models.ImageField(db_column='POA_IMAGE', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def client_create_view(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     form = ClientCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
        else:
          pass
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield), this is not how ImageField and FileField works, they save in MEDIA_ROOT and add the path to the database. You should use [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) instead.

Comment: Yes, you can for sure.

Comment: How to save it as Binary, I tried it but could not do it . I have have asked it as other question

Comment: You have to handle the saving manually, and don't depend of the form saving it

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, it should be "BYTEA" instead of "BLOB".

Comment: Good to know , Wish I get what I am seeking for